# Ошибка "syntax error, unexpected T_IF"

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, у меня браузер выдает вот такую ошибку: "syntax error, unexpected T_IF". Не знаю, что делать, могу выслать листинг...

Comment: Высылай, посмотрим

Comment: Незакрытая скобка, пропущенная точка с запятой или что-то в этом духе, пройдитесь внимательно по коду.

Answer (score 1):

Нужен листинг. Проблема же в том, что вы где-то потеряли фигурную скобку. Проверьте последний редактированный код редактором с динамической подсветкой.

Answer (score 0):

у меня была ошибка из-за

```
<? php
if ...
?>
```

а надо было `<?php` - писать слитно